# Multiprocessing vs multithreading for Parse large files. And maintain a counter for no. of lines processed altogether

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, large-files

I have lot of large files containing plain text(comma separated).
Need to perform some action on every line and keep a tracker count of total number of lines processed irrespective of the number of files processed.

I'm not sure which option approach would be better (multiprocessing or multithreading)?

I tried implementing multiprocessing but the time difference of sequential processing or multiprocessing didn't differ much.
   - It might be I didn't apply multiprocessing correctly.

```
global_counter

def process_file():
   with open(file, 'r') as f, open(file.done, 'w') as df, open(file.err, 'w') as ef:
      #some operations on file
      #based on some operation logs, work on df or ef.
      #increment global_counter with every line

records = process_file()
t = Pool(processes=8)
for i in records:
   t.map(processing, (i,))
t.close()
```

Time of execution remained the same.
I want to implement `multiprocessing/multithreading` to reduce time in processing multiple large files.

Kindly help me in deciding which of the 2 approach would be better for my case.

Comment: Actually, you can try both by yourself and see what approach is faster. We do not know the operations that you use in your context manager. If they do not execute too much Python code, but work with some kind of network operations or so, it is better to use multithreading than multiprocessing and vice versa.

Comment: Also you use Python 2 as mentioned in tags, so there are some differences between Python 2 and 3 multiprocessing and multithreading, I do not know them exactly, but you still can find them. Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks SampleText2k77 for your input. But the operation I need to perform with every line would be some `subprocess` call and some framework call which will provide output. `subprocess` calls are slow and `framework` calls would also be slow.